# Use sed to comment out .env entry

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I'm writing a script that will comment and un-comment field in .env file.

```
sed -i "s/#SENDGRID_API_KEY/SENDGRID_API_KEY/g" $mlEnv
```

for uncomment

```
sed -i "s/[^#]SENDGRID_API_KEY/#SENDGRID_API_KEY/g" $mlEnv
```

for comment out, I use `[^#]` so that it will not add one more # when it is already commented

But second one doesnt work, although

```
grep "[^#]SENDGRID_API_KEY" $mlEnv
```

works ok.

Comment: Use `sed -i -E 's/(^|[^#])(SENDGRID_API_KEY)/\1#\2/g' $mlEnv`

Comment: It works, can you explain that?

Comment: Your fundamental mistake is assuming that `[^#]` means "not preceded by". But it actually means "require a single character here which is not `#`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i -E 's/(^|[^#])(SENDGRID_API_KEY)/\1#\2/g' "$mlEnv"
```

Here, `-E` enables POSIX ERE regex syntax, `(^|[^#])` captures (into Group 1) either start of string or any char but `#` in Group 1 and `(SENDGRID_API_KEY)` captures `SENDGRID_API_KEY` in Group 2.

The `\1#\2` replacement pattern replaces with Group 1 contents + `#` + Group 2 contents.

Variables which specify a file name argument should generally be within double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ei 's/^#?(SENDGRID_API_KEY)/#\1/' file
```

This will replace a line beginning `#SENDGRID_API_KEY` or `SENDGRID_API_KEY` with `#SENDGRID_API_KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

Another try with `sed` similar to potong's:

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*#*[[:space:]]*\(SENDGRID_API_KEY\)/#\1/' file > newfile
```

The `^[[:space:]]*#*[[:space:]]*\(SENDGRID_API_KEY\)` pattern matches any whitespace, 0+ hash chars, then again any whitespaces and then a `SENDGRID_API_KEY` word captured in Group 1. The replacement is `#` and then the captured value.